# javascript distorts font

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, cleartype

I've noticed the font is not displayed clear on my website. 
It is due to the javascript but I can not find the problem. Does anyone
know what is wrong?

The border of the font is not straight. Looks something like cleartype not being set. The problem is in mu FF4 browsers.
Font-weight is definitely different when the javascript is turned off (less).

Edit: I see what is the problem the Jquery background function.
Does it overrule all of the css body statements? Is there a way to just add the background only to the body?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

 $.fn.smartBackgroundImage = function(url){
  var t = this;
  $('<img />')
    .attr('src', url)
    .load(function(){ 
       t.each(function(){ 
          $(this).css('background', '#16171e url('+url+') right bottom no-repeat fixed');
       });
    });
   return this;
 }

var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
jQuery.post('/v3/ajax/portview.php', {height: viewportHeight, width: viewportWidth});

if (viewportWidth>950) {
 $('body').smartBackgroundImage('http://sionvalais.com/gfx/berge.jpg');
}

});
```

Comment: Looks more like an ad for your site than a question. Can you be _a lot_ more specific? Are you certain the issue is not with _your_ browser?

Comment: Your site looks the same with or without JS. Voting to close till you add more details

Comment: @mark, looks the same to me. You should attach screenshots to the question and ping us by adding `@username` in the comments.

Comment: @Oded @JohnP Would you reopen my post?

Comment: @Blender @emmett ping to reopen post

Comment: @mark I've flagged the post for mod attention. Please also add a screenshot so we know how it looks with and without the code. I don't see a difference when I enable/disable FF. But it looks a bit weird in chrome